# Plotting from a certain threshold in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that has 3 columns: Date, value1, value 2. I have plotted these on a graph using matplotlib. 
Is it possible in python to start plotting from a certain date? For example my dataset starts from 1950 but I want it to start plotting when date = 1990 instead of 1950.

Here is an example of my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953,1954,1955,1956],
'value1': [23, 57, 78, 62, 80, 67, 98],
'value2': [42, 55, 45, 80, 27, 56, 87]
})
```

Using the above example I would like to plot from 1953 instead of 1950

Comment: `df[df['date']>=1953].plot(...)`?

Comment: I set “date” to datetime and set it as the index. Could this be the reason why this is not working

Comment: If it’s index just do df.loc[1953:].plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the dataframe like this according to your criteria -

```
filt = df[df['date'] >= 1953]
```

You could them plot `filt`.

Comment: I set “date” to datetime and set it as the index. Could this be the reason why this is not working ?

Comment: If `date` is set as index, try - `filt = df[df.index >= 1953]` and then plot `filt`.